# Unable to figure out how Laravel ACL(Gate) works

Tags: php, laravel, acl

As per [tutorial](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#defining-abilities), I added facade in `app.php` and defined ability like following but some how my application is not reading Authentication Provider. Following is my Auth Service Provider class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        parent::registerPolicies($gate);
        dd("duh");
        $gate->define('update-contact', function ($user) {
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

In controller I did following but it always goes to `no`:

```
if (Gate::allows('update-contact')) {
    dd("allowed");
} else {
    dd("no");
}
```

*Update*: I am a bit confused. The doc says:

> The AuthServiceProvider which ships with Laravel serves as a
>   convenient location to define all of the abilities for your
>   application.

Do I have to Create a Service Provider Manually via `make:Service` command?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#checking-abilities) documentation, you’ll see a second parameter needs to be passed:

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

Authorization checks a user can do something with a particular object. In the above case, checks whether the user can update the specified `$post`. So when it comes to checking, you need to specify that second parameter:

```
if (Gate::allows('update-post', $post)) {
    //
}
```

In your case, you’ll need to modify your check to accept an instance of whatever a “contact” is in your application.

Comment: I got your point but issue is, my application is not even entering in `boot` method.

Comment: Have you added the AuthServiceProvider class to the `providers` array in **config/app.php**?

Comment: Yes it was added on `composer update` as *Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class*

Answer (score 0):

if you used this one 
**use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract** 
then you need to call as **GateContract**

```
if (GateContract::allows('update-contact')) {
            dd("allowed");
        }
        else {
            dd("no");
        }
```

Comment: I am reading Docs and getting confused. It is not clear whether do I have to create `AuthServiceProvider` myself or have to make changes in one shipped by Laravel. :/

Comment: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GateContract' not found`

Comment: Ok, the issue was: I did not register my own created Provided in `app.php`. I'd like you to create this as answer since you gave the hint. Laraven `Authorization` was not clear at all.